# TSQL: Join tables based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The resultset I am aiming to receive is this:

[image: required resultset]

My table structure is like:

[image: table structure]

The `INVOICE` table has `INVTYPE` column which defines whether the invoice is a sales invoice or a purchase invoice by holding 101 for sale and 201 for purchase.

My query will use a where statement to also filter down the `STOCK` table to a particular `STOCKCODE`.

I am trying to filter out products (`STOCK`) with a `STOCKCODE = "XYZ"`

If I run

```
SELECT * 
FROM STOCK 
WHERE STOCKCODE = 'XYZ'
```

I get 152 results. So I have 152 products with a `STOCKCODE` of 'XYZ' for sure..

My problem is when I try to join these tables. For simplicity, I have only tried to get `INVTYPE` 101 to keep it simple but my desired outcome is still with the 201.

I have tried joins and subqueries such as:

```
SELECT 
    S.STOCKNO, S.STOCKNAME, ISNULL(SUM(IIT.QTYSOLD), 0) AS QTY, 
    ISNULL(SUM(IIT.TOTAL), 0) AS TOTAL 
FROM 
    STOCK S
LEFT JOIN 
    INVOICE_ITEM IIT ON S.STOCKID = IIT.STOCKID
LEFT JOIN 
    INVOICE INV ON IIT.INVID = INV.INVID
WHERE 
    S.STOCKCODE = 'XYZ' AND INV.TRANSTYPE = 101
GROUP BY 
    S.STOCKNO, S.STOCKNAME
```

This query returns 122 results. So I know that there are 30 items in the stock table that have not been sold, which I need to show them in the resultset with 0 (zero) in the relevant columns.

I also tried this:

```
SELECT 
    S.STOCKNO, S.STOCKNAME, 
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(TOTAL), 0) 
     FROM INVOICE_ITEM IIT 
     WHERE IIT.STOCKID = S.STOCKID) AS TOTAL,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QTYSOLD), 0) 
     FROM INVOICE_ITEM IIT 
     WHERE IIT.STOCKID = S.STOCKID) AS QTY
FROM 
    STOCK S 
WHERE 
    S.STOCKCODE = 'XYZ'
```

This query return the full 152 results because I did not filter by `INVTYPE` it returned the items which were purchased as well.

I am using SQL Server 2014

So my question is how can I achieve my desired resultset? and what am I doing wrong with my joins?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a conditional aggregation

```
SELECT S.STOCKNO, 
       S.STOCKNAME, 
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN INV.TRANSTYPE = 201 THEN IIT.TOTAL END), 0) AS TOTAL_PURCHASED,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN INV.TRANSTYPE = 101 THEN IIT.TOTAL END), 0) AS TOTAL_SOLD,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN INV.TRANSTYPE = 201 THEN IIT.QTYSOLD END),0) AS QTY_PURCHASED, 
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN INV.TRANSTYPE = 101 THEN IIT.QTYSOLD END),0) AS QTY_SOLD 
FROM STOCK S
LEFT JOIN INVOICE_ITEM IIT ON S.STOCKID = IIT.STOCKID
LEFT JOIN INVOICE INV ON IIT.INVID= INV.INVID
WHERE S.STOCKCODE= 'XYZ'
GROUP BY S.STOCKNO, S.STOCKNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

since you are not joining your inner tables (INVOICE_ITEM) with their primary key this is an expected behavior.

you either need to use INVITEMID column for your join, you need to add STOCKID and INVID together.

```
 SELECT ISNULL(SUM(TOTAL),0) FROM INVOICE_ITEM IIT 
 WHERE IIT.STOCKID = S.STOCKID and IIT.INVID = INV.INVID
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance, it is tempting to try:

```
select s.stockno, s.stockname,
       coalesce(i.total_purchased, 0) as total_purchased,
       coalesce(i.total_sold, 0) as total_sold,
       coalesce(i.qty_purchased, 0) as qty_purchased,
       coalesce(i.qty_sold, 0) as qty_sold
from stock s outer apply
     (select sum(case when i.transtype = 201 then ii.total end) as total_purchased,
             sum(case when i.transtype = 101 then ii.total end) as total_sold,
             sum(case when i.transtype = 201 then ii.qtysold end) as qty_purchased,
             sum(case when i.transtype = 101 then ii.qtysold end) as qty_sold             
      from invoice_item ii join
           invoice i
           on ii.invid = i.invid
      where s.stockid = ii.stockid
     ) i
where stockcode = 'XYZ'
```